# In Dark Souls 2, What does this signal-emitting icon mean?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 2, **what does the encircled icon below mean?** I notice that it only appears while in online multiplayer.

[image: Signal-emitting icon]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means you have voice chat enabled and there are other players in the same world, and they should be able to hear you speak to your microphone.

Comment: Do you have a source for that or is it personal experience?

Comment: Personal experience.

Comment: Why is it that I can't hear them?

Comment: @brain56 They probably have voice chat disabled (and I don't blame them)..

Comment: Is there something I did to enable it? I read somewhere that you needed a ring for voice chat, but I don't remember having one.

Comment: @brain56 https://i.3v.fi/2014-05-03_00001.jpg

Comment: @3ventic Linking to outside sources is ok, but you should provide some text so that, if/when the link goes dead (as it has in this case), people can still be helped..